# Use video/mp4 for mimetype in electron project

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, blob, mime-types

So I have been working on this screen recorder using electron using this [tutorial](https://fireship.io/lessons/electron-screen-recorder-project-tutorial/) and it is working just fine, but it records in *.webm* format, is there a simple way that I can make it record in *.mp4* using mimetype and correct codec or some other way

My recorder looks like this:

```js
const constraints = {
   audio: false,
   video: {
     mandatory: {
       chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
       chromeMediaSourceId: source.id
     }
   }
 };

 const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices
   .getUserMedia(constraints);

 //LOOK HERE
 const options = { mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9' };  
 mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
```

All the data being recorded is pushed in an array and then converted to a blob for raw data, the blob declaration looks like this:

```
const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
      type: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9'
    });
```

And if someone can also suggest me how to add audio recording too, in this application, that would be very neat.

Answer (score 0):

Though this post is old, I also faced this problem and this is what I ended up doing,

You cannot directly add audio with desktop recording in electron, instead, you should create two separate streams for audio and video and then merge them into one

```
// separate contraints for video options

const videoconstraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
        chromeMediaSourceId: source.id
      }
    }
  };

// separate constraints for audio options
const audioconstraints = {audio: true};


// two different streams for audio and video
const audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(audioconstraints);
const videoStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(videoconstraints);

// now you can combine both the streams to get one single stream
const stream = new MediaStream([...videoStream.getVideoTracks(), ...audioStream.getAudioTracks()])
```

as for the first part, I am also looking for a solution.